# Passing a reference of parent class to child

Tags: class, coffeescript

I'm trying to pass a reference to a parent class instance to its child class. The parent class is:

```
class UI

  constructor: (parameters) ->

    @addBTS = new AddBTS
    @toolbar = new Toolbar(this)
```

The AddBts and Toolbar classes are:

```
class Toolbar
  constructor: (@parent) ->

  add_bts_clickhandler: () =>
    $('body').on 'click', '#add_bts', ->
      @parent.addBTS.display()
```

```
class AddBTS
  constructor: () ->


  display: () =>
    $("#setBuildingTileSet").show()
    console.log 'Showing Sir'
```

All these classes are defined in separate CoffeeScript files and are joined together before comalation in the following order (Game is where the instance of UI lives):

```
  'src/Game'
  'src/UI/UI'
  'src/UI/AddBTS'
  'src/UI/Toolbar'
```

No, when I call `add_bts_clickhandler: ()` I get the error message: * Cannot read property 'addBTS' of undefined *

So it thinks that parent is undefined, when it's clearly not.

Please could someone help me, I'm completely stuck as my code seams fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution:

I call add_bts_clickhandler:

```
ui = new window.UI();
ui.toolbar.add_bts_clickhandler();
```

My classes:

```
class window.UI
  constructor: (parameters) ->
    @addBTS = new window.AddBTS
    @toolbar = new window.Toolbar(this)


class window.AddBTS
  constructor: () ->

  display: () =>
    $("#setBuildingTileSet").show()
    console.log 'Showing Sir'


class window.Toolbar
  constructor: (@parent) ->

  add_bts_clickhandler: () =>
    p = @parent  ## introduce a new variable!
    $('body').on 'click', '#add_bts', ->
      p.addBTS.display(); ##
      #@parent.addBTS.display()
```

Let us look Toolbar class a bit closer:

```
class window.Toolbar
    constructor: (@parent) ->

    add_bts_clickhandler: () =>
        $('body').on 'click', '#add_bts', ->
            @parent.addBTS.display()
```

Part of the generated javascript:

```
Toolbar.prototype.add_bts_clickhandler = function() {
    return $('body').on('click', '#add_bts', function() {
        return this.parent.addBTS.display();
    });
};
```

In this line: return **this**.parent.addBTS.display();
**this** refers to the callback function()! not to the add_bts_clickhandler.

I hope I helped you.